# Receive Token from redirect (Azure Ad)

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have a method which fetches the token via the Azure Ad (via the link). The redirect points to the method "ReceiveToken". When the login to Microsoft is done, a redirect is made with the token in the URL. The method "ReceiveToken" is called, but the parameters of the method are null. How do I get the token from the URL to use the access_token in the method.

```
[HttpGet("token")]
     public void GetATokenForGraph()
    {

        var concatURL = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/-/oauth2/v2.0/authorize" +
                   "?client_id=-" +
                   "&response_type=-" +
                   "&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A5000%2Foauth%2F" +
                   "&scope=-" +
                   "&response_mode=-" +
                   "&state=-" +
                   "&nonce=-";

        Process myProcess = new Process();

        try
        {
            // true is the default, but it is important not to set it to false
            myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = concatURL;
            myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            myProcess.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
    }

[HttpGet]
    public void ReceiveToken([FromRoute] string access_token, [FromRoute] string token_type, [FromRoute] string expires_in,
                             [FromRoute] string scope, [FromRoute] string state, [FromRoute] string session_state)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(access_token);   
    }
```

URL: https://localhost:5000/oauth/#access_token=.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below code to get `access_token`.

```
// get url from this command text
var concatURL = "echo test";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
process.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
process.StartInfo.Arguments = "/C "+concatURL;
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
process.Start();
string result = "";
while (!process.HasExited)
{
    result += process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
Console.WriteLine(result);
Console.ReadKey();
```

**Test Result**

[image]